# Sql writes data through php script but doesn't show result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Good day! I came with my first problem in coding :(
here is my php script:

```
case'reload-mobs':
$slctmob=$_POST['slctmob'];
$howmanymobs=$_POST['howmanymobs'];
if(!$slctmob){echo"No mobs were selected!...<br/>";echo"<a href=\"$cp?pg=mob-control&action=reload\">OK</a><br/>";exit;}
if($howmanymobs==0){echo"Please select how many!...<br/>";echo"<a href=\"$cp?pg=mob-control&action=reload\">OK</a><br/>";exit;}
if($howmanymobs>100){echo"Cannot select more than 100!...<br/>";echo"<a href=\"$cp?pg=mob-control&action=reload\">OK</a><br/>";exit;}   
$gj11 = file_get_contents("core/mob/$slctmob");
$mob = explode("\n", $gj11);
if($mob[11]==$slctmob){
    echo"Mob <b>$mob[11]</b> founded...<br/>";
    echo"Mob reloading in <b>$mob[9]</b> started...<br/>";
        #1 - Deleting all old mobs...
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM loc WHERE type='mob' AND loc='$mob[9]'")or die(mysql_error());
        echo"Deleted all old <b>$mob[11]</b> mobs...<br/>";
        #2 - Writing all new mobs...
        foreach (range(1, $howmanymobs) as $rs) {
            $mobname=$slctmob.'.'.$rs;
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO loc SET nick='$mobname', loc='$mob[9]', hp='$mob[2]', type='mob'")or die(mysql_error());
            echo"Added <b>$mobname</b> to <b>$mob[9]</b>..<br/>";
        }
        echo"Mobs refresh ended...<br/>";

    echo"<a href=\"$cp?pg=mob-control&action=reload\">OK</a><br/>";
}else{
    echo"Mob <b>$slctmob</b> not founded in database! Check <b>MOBS.list</b> file if name is correct and try again!...<br/>";
    echo"<a href=\"$cp?pg=mob-control&action=reload\">OK</a><br/>";
    exit;
}
    break;
```

This script automatically adds data to sql db. It used to work correctly, but now when i adding stuff via this script it won't show in my site tho.. But it's interesting that when i add the same information in sql db using PhpMyAdmin panel it will appear in my site.. but using this code won't appear.. Please tell me what it is.. i don't get it.. my phpMyAdmin version - 3.5.6

Comment: Did you check to see if the data is in the db? If it is, your error is with the code getting it out. If it isn't, then you problem lies here.

Comment: gah... why are you using files when you're already obviously using a database?

Comment: John - yes, data appears in sql, but my page wont show them, but when i add the same data usin phpMyAdmin, my site shows it. Marc - idk.. its from my old project tho..

Comment: There must be some difference in the data that's added by this script and data you add by hand with phpMyAdmin. Maybe a null field versus a field with an empty string.

Comment: it might help if you posted the script that displays the database contents.

Comment: ` $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loc WHERE loc='$loc' ORDER BY id");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  if($row[type]=="mob"){
   echo $mob_info[0].' '.$row[hp].'hp '.$mobLVL.'lvl <a href="'.PROJECT_LOCATION.'/battle.pvn.php?pg=target&mob='.$row['nick'].'">[Pulti]</a></br>';
  } 
  if($row[type]=="player"){
   echo $row['nick'] .' '.$inforow['lvl'].'lvl'.$showAFK.''.$showAFKtime.'s.</br>';
  }
 }` hope it helps..

Comment: oh and another thing - i tried the same query use in my php script as in phpMyAdmin but no luck tho :(